# how to limit the rotation of a rigid leg

Tags: rigging, constraints

I can't seem to limit the rotation of a rigged leg with IK.
I've added a Limit Rotation bone constraint but without success.

This is the first time i'm rigging something so I must miss a basic rules?

Do I apply the bone constraint to the control bone or the deform bone?
If the answer is deform bone, which one?

I also noticed that you can limit the movement in the Inverse Kinematics section of the Bone properties panel. Should I use this instead of the bone constraint?

[image]

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-Lm_JsuIYkzYftWQEhozsVjVl0y7woUD/view?usp=sharing

Thanks for your help!

Comment: the constraints won't work along the IK chain, so, as you say, you need to use the the Limit XYZ in the Bone panel > Inverse Kinematics

Comment: I can put a constraint on the bones by using the Lock IK function but when I then use the control bone it's not working anymore ...

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Hp1N-CGxG5Ve8KiB9WhKjp4Y_RN_HFDG/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Yes it's hard to handle, I'm a bit lost with these bone limits   :(

Comment: Actually the best way to control the leg os to use the pole target bone, for the moment it's a bit too close to the knee, what are you trying to achieve exactly, why do you want to use the limits?

Comment: OK so actually I think that the problem comes from the fact that the pole target prevent the limits to work properly, so I guess you either need to use the pole target (but place it correctly) or use limits